# CSS Grid: How to make a variable number of columns fill remaining space

Tags: css-grid

The `<page-header>` and `<page-footer>` stretch across a variable number of `<page-panel>` columns using...

```
page-header,
page-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

[image]

This line of CSS is auto generating columns based off of the fixed `200px` width.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

[image]

How to change `200px` to a variable width to stretch to fill up remaining space *without wrapping the columns and without adding extra markup like a parent element*?

`auto`, `auto-fit`, `auto-fill`, `1fr`, `100%` all make the columns into full width rows which is undesirable.

Ideas/suggestions/solutions are welcome.

Thank you much!

CodePen: https://codepen.io/dragontheory/pen/MWOKpNr

HTML:

```
<page-container>
  <page-header>
    <span>HEADER</span>
  </page-header>
  <page-panel></page-panel>
  <page-panel></page-panel>
  <page-panel></page-panel>
  <page-footer>
    <span>FOOTER</span>
  </page-footer>
</page-container>
```

CSS:

```
page-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
page-container > * {
  display: grid;
}
page-header,
page-footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  padding: 1rem;
}
page-panel { 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```